# Tableau: Is there a way to use a sub-groups values to add values to a member of the "main" group?

Tags: tableau-api

I have faculty members whose productivity I'm calculating. I need to add 3 interns productivity to the faculty they assist. Is it possible to create such a grouping?

I'm calculating productivity as in total values/days worked.

I tried to use a LOD but I'm not strong with them, so I'm not sure if it's the LOD or it can't be done.
LOD: {FIXED [FACULTY]='GROUP1': SUM([NUMBER OF VALUES]/[DAYS WORKED]}

Thanks

Comment: Hi Theo, can you describe your data? What do the relevant rows and columns look like?

Comment: Try this ` {FIXED [FACULTY]: SUM([NUMBER OF VALUES]/[DAYS WORKED]}`